# Is linq to sql able to automatically update foreign keys

Tags: c#, linq

While playing around with 1:n relationships using EntitySet, a question came to my mind:

Say I have two classes A and B and I want to establish an A (1) ---> B (n) relationship

On DB level I have 2 tables A and B, where the table B has a reference column "AId" and a FK constraint to ensure that AId references a primary key of a record in table A. I then added an EntitySet in class A to access many B records as members of A (1:n). Ids are autogenerated.

So far so good. But when I now create a new A and add a B to its entity set and call submitChanges() it will fail with a FK violation because B's AId column is set to 0.

My question: Is linq-to-sql supposed to automatically care about assigning the correct Id to all B's in its entity set when I submit the changes? Or do I need to take care about that by myself (insert an A first, set the referencing id on all B's accordingly, then insert the B's?)

All examples on the web just use queries - I didn't find any examples about **storing** 1:n relationships.

Thx and regards

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using Linq-to-SQL instead of Entity Framework?

Comment: So far we're using hard coded sql statements - linq to sql seems a better approach and easier to introduce. But I haven't had a close look to entity framework, as it seems to be even more complex.

Comment: Entity Framework is the successor to Linq-to-SQL (thought it took until v2 to reach feature parity). They both work in similar ways and EF is far more flexible and powerful (and supports other DBMS too). I strongly suggest you give EF a try first.